# Couldn't type pipe in iterm2 and comma in Phpstorm

Tags: keyboard, iterm

I switched from Linux to Mac and I have some issues with my keyboard and I don't know why. I know how to write a pipe in mac with Alt/Option, however it's doesn't work in Iterm2. Nevertheless, it works with Right Option + 7 but not with Left Option.

My second issue is with my IDE Phpstorm. I realize that I couldn't type a comma. But this problem only occurs when I call a method or function and try to commit them arguments and separate them with a comma. Phpstorm doesn't type my comma. Maybe I should ask the JetBrains support, but I guess it's a Mac issue.

My notebook is running Big Sur 11.5.1 and I use a german keyboard. My system language is english.

Thanks for help

Comment: Does this only affect those 2 apps? can you type pipe & comma in here, for instance? If your keyboard is set to English, the positions may not match the keyboard, comma is first right of M and pipe is shift + third right of L [right next to the 'hole' in the Return key] This is probably more even confusing if you have a PC keyboard, as Mac & PC put the pipe key in totally different places] - https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYHvp.png