# Can't type tilde on iterm2 on German keyboard

Tags: macos, command-line, iterm

I try to type the left option key and n for typing `~` on my iterm2 but it doesn't work. When I do the same with the right <kbd>Option</kbd> key I can type a `~`. After it I can type `~` with the left <kbd>Option</kbd> key until I have press the spacebar.

My notebook is running Big Sur 11.5.1 and I use a german keyboard. My system language is english.

I'm total confused and have no idea why it's [not working for pipe and tilde](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/425148/5472) :/

Comment: Does this happen in other apps - like Terminal or Notes?

Comment: What language keyboard do you have & what is your input language set to?

Comment: My Keyboard Input source under System Preferences is German and this happen only in Iterm2 :/

Comment: This may be different depending on your input language, but for me opt-n doesn't type a tilde, it puts text entry in a mode where the next character will be combined with a tilde. So typing opt-n followed by another n types a ñ. Typing opt-n followed by space does insert a ~, but I wonder if it's not "typing" a ~ in the traditional sense which a shell might require. To type a tilde on my qwerty keyboard there is a key to the right of the left shift, and on other keyboards I have seen it to the left of the 1. Sorry I don't have a complete answer.

Comment: I guess only screenshots of keyboards could help for such issues, right?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue with a French keyboard, found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61700443/tilde-isnt-responsive-in-iterm-after-configuring-a-hotkey-window). You need to configure in iTerm settings > Profiles > Your profile(s) > Keys > Left/Right Option Key to "Normal" for that key to work as usual.